# Formatting scraped HTML data into excel using VBA - won't display properly

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am working on a VBA script and I am stuck on something that should be so easy. Anyways, the VBA code takes a member number from sheet1, opens an authenticated IE window, pops in a member number, scrapes certain tables from the HTML page and inserts them into Sheet 2. Then it moves on to the next member number from Sheet1. However I am struggling getting the scraped data into sheet2. When I run the code everything goes according to plan, except that everything is just inserted into the same spot in sheet2 every time. So when the code is done all I have is the data from the last member on sheet1.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TableExample()
Dim IE As Object
Dim doc As Object
Dim strURL As String
Dim hicN As String


strURL = "exampleURL.com"

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With IE
     .Visible = True
    .navigate strURL
            Do Until .ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop
            Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop
            Set doc = IE.Document

                Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)


                    memNum = ActiveCell

                     doc.getelementbyid("claimNumber").Value = memNum
                    doc.all("submitBtn").Click

                     Do While .Busy: DoEvents: Loop

                     GetAllTables doc, memNum



                      ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
                Loop

            '.Quit
        End With
    End Sub
```

The GetAllTables method-

```
    Sub GetAllTables(doc As Object, memNum As String)

         ' get all the tables from a webpage document, doc, and put them in a new worksheet

        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim rng As Range
        Dim tbl As Object
        Dim rw As Object
        Dim cl As Object
        Dim tabno As Long
        Dim nextrow As Long
        Dim I As Long


       Set ws = Sheet2


        For Each tbl In doc.getElementsByTagName("TABLE")
            tabno = tabno + 1


        If tabno = 11 Or tabno = 13 Or tabno = 16 Then

                nextrow = nextrow + 1
                Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)
                'Debug.Print nextrow
                rng.Offset(, -1) = memNum
                For Each rw In tbl.Rows
                    For Each cl In rw.Cells
                        rng.Value = cl.outerText
                        Set rng = rng.Offset(, 1)
                        I = I + 1
                    Next cl
                    nextrow = nextrow + 1
                    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, -I)
                    I = 0
                Next rw

            End If

        Next tbl


    End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you could give the exact url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare  `nextrow` as a global variable and it should work

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`Set rng = ws.Range("B" & nextrow)`

use this

It will put the data in the next available row - column B

```
 With ws
       Set rng = .Range("B" & .Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row).Offset(1, 0)
  End With
```